# Secondary Workflow Not Starting

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have two lists each having its own workflow. List 1 is using Workflow A and is set to start automatically when an item is created or edited. List 2 has Workflow B and is set to start automatically only when an item is created.

The user only edits List 1, and Workflow A has a condition if a checkbox is set to "Yes" then it creates an item in List 2.

**This Issue:** When the item is created in List 2, Workflow B does not run automatically.

I've looked into this extensively, and the most common culprit in these cases is that Workflow A would be impersonating as "System Account" rather than the user's account. However, I do not see this as the case, for I checked the "Created By" column on List 2's item and did not see "System Account".

Also, this is a 2013 workflow, and I could not find the "Impersonation Step" capability in SP Designer.

Comment: Doesn't speak to all of the question, but the "Impersonation Step" does not exist in SPD2013. There is a site feature for this instead. Once ‘Workflows can use app permissions’  is enabled, when you get to the necessary point, add in App Step giving permissions (App Step is the key icon in the workflow ribbon menu).

Comment: I enabled 'Workflows can use app permissions' and then added an App Step into Workflow A (I placed the line where it creates an item in Workflow B into the App Step). However, Workflow B is still not starting.